# how to test a negative test case scenario in selenium webdriver using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, testcase

```
try{
IList<IWebElement> DropdownMenus = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='table-archive']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
               // Console.Write("List of TTMCs are: ");
               foreach (IWebElement ele1 in DropdownMenus)
               {
                   //Console.ReadLine("Enter the TTMC name");
                    string value = "Basavanagudi";
                  // string value = ele1.Text;
                   Console.WriteLine(value);
                   if (value.Equals("Shanthinagar") | value.Equals("Jayanagar") | value.Equals("Kengeri") | value.Equals("Banashankari") | value.Equals("Koramangala") | value.Equals("Yeshawanthapura") | value.Equals("Vijayanagar") | value.Equals("Domlur") | value.Equals("Whitefield") | value.Equals("Bannerghatta"))
                       Console.WriteLine("true");
                   else
                       throw new NoSuchElementException("Basavangudi");
               }
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception is: {0}, message is: {1}", e.InnerException, e.Message);
           }
```

*I have written both positive test case scenario as well as negative test case scenario, where in which my test case has to fail If my findelement is not found, so I used Try Catch block and here exception is handled at catch block so my test case is not failing, how to make my test case to fail?*

Comment: Are you using Nunit ot xUnit testing framework ? or is this a demo without any framework ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I am using NUnit

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change all the `|` to `||` in the

```
if (value.Equals("Shanthinagar") | value.Equals("Jayanagar") | value.Equals("Kengeri") | value.Equals("Banashankari") | value.Equals("Koramangala") | value.Equals("Yeshawanthapura") | value.Equals("Vijayanagar") | value.Equals("Domlur") | value.Equals("Whitefield") | value.Equals("Bannerghatta"))
```

line.

Comment: too quick without proper answer :)

Comment: I learned from you. It's you who running to answer and then updating the answer 10 times :)

Comment: even after making those changes, its not working

Comment: Yeah that's a good technique. I should say

Comment: You did not answer my question. I can't see `try` here but I do see `catch`

Comment: But why not to do it? To make understanding your code harder? It's not enough difficult to try to understand code appearing partially, without highlighting, without a way to run and debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest you to have a **separate test case** for `negative scenario`, do not combine `positive test cases with negative test cases`. As doing so can cause **unpredictable** test result outcome and will always have a question on reliability.

If not, you only have one **option** left that is to use `data driven testing :`

you can probably do something like this :

```
[TestCase("valid city name 1", TestName = "Positive test case - 1")]
[TestCase("valid city name 2", TestName = "Positive test case - 2")]
[TestCase("Invalid city 1", TestName = "Negative testing - 1")]
public void CombPositiveNegativeTesting(string cityName){

// rest of your here
if (value.Equals($"cityName"))
       Console.WriteLine("true");
else
  //throw new NoSuchElementException("Basavangudi");
  Assert.AreEqual("Actual value ", "Expected value");
               }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to implement the above code? Because even then my test case is not failing

Comment: those are Nunit attribute, just type [TestCase] and follow the same

Comment: I got that point but not getting the expected result